# Missing compatible version from cocopods in flutter /firebase project

Tags: firebase, flutter, cocoapods

just git a big problem with the installed pods on my flutter/firebase project.

Get this message every time after "pod install":

```
"Analyzing dependencies
cloud_firestore: Using Firebase SDK version '8.0.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
cloud_functions: Using Firebase SDK version '8.0.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_analytics: Using Firebase SDK version '8.0.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_auth: Using Firebase SDK version '8.0.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '8.0.0' defined in 'firebase_core'


[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "cloud_firestore":
  In Podfile:
    cloud_firestore (from `.symlinks/plugins/cloud_firestore/ios`)

Specs satisfying the `cloud_firestore (from `.symlinks/plugins/cloud_firestore/ios`)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target."
```

Im on a Mac M1, but most tricks from stack overflow aso don't help much.

Already installed with "sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi" & "arch -x86_64 pod install"

Heres are the dependencies:

```
flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_core: ^1.3.0
  firebase_analytics: ^8.1.2
  firebase_auth: ^1.4.1
  cloud_firestore: ^2.2.0+1
  cloud_functions: ^1.1.2
```

After deleting one, the given message from above appears with a new pod.

I really don't know what to do after hours...

thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You can try this way,

First Flutter clean then, From ios folder delete .symlinks, Pods, Podfile.lock and Runner.xcworkspace.

then run pub get.

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: if there are no .symlinks in my ios folder, is that a problem?

Comment: no it doesn't work, message appears again; but now I don't have a runner.xcworkspace

Comment: [!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "cloud_firestore":
  In Podfile:
    cloud_firestore (from `.symlinks/plugins/cloud_firestore/ios`)

Specs satisfying the `cloud_firestore (from `.symlinks/plugins/cloud_firestore/ios`)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
 its the same issue again and again...